# AngularJS putting logic in Service rather than Controller, Best practices

Tags: angularjs, service, firebase

I have a controller that gathers data from a firebase. I use it all over my site, so it's called all the time.

```
app.controller("ReplicatedController", function($scope, $routeParams, $firebaseObject) {

  var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
  var refSubdomain = parts.shift();

  var ref = new Firebase("https://example-firebase.firebaseio.com/" + refSubdomain);
  var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
  syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "coach");

  if($routeParams.my_affiliate){
    var myAffiliate = $routeParams.my_affiliate;
    window.location = "http://" + myAffiliate + ".example.com";
  };

});
```

This works just fine, but my question is should I move this into a service? And would that make it so I am accessing my Firebase less often?

Also what is the best way to move something like this into a service. Do I just create a service.

```
app.factory('ReplicatedService', ['$http', function($scope, $routeParams, $firebaseObject){
  var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
  var refSubdomain = parts.shift();

  var ref = new Firebase("https://example-firebase.firebaseio.com/" + refSubdomain);
  var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
  syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "coach");

  if($routeParams.my_affiliate){
    var myAffiliate = $routeParams.my_affiliate;
    window.location = "http://" + myAffiliate + ".example.com";
  };

});
```

Then call the service from my Controller?

```
app.controller('ReplicatedController', ['$scope','ReplicatedService', function($scope,ReplicatedService){

}]);
```

I can't seem to get this to work. Also why do I need to change it? Will it boost performance, or just make cleaner more readable code?

Comment: Yes, all API calls/business logics, IMO, should be in a service and then reused. Controllers link your views and business logic/Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factory provider isn't returning anything. To access it, you need to actually return the synchronized object.

```
app.factory('ReplicatedService', ['$http', function($scope, $routeParams, $firebaseObject){
  var parts = location.hostname.split('.');
  var refSubdomain = parts.shift();

  ...

  return syncObject;
});

app.controller('...', function(ReplicatedService) {
   $scope.data = ReplicatedService;
});
```

This is a typical case of debugging via simplification. To work this out yourself, you would begin by breaking this down into the smallest working component you could conceive:

```
app.factory('test', function() {
   return { foo: 'bar' };
});

app.controller('...', function($scope, test) {
   $scope.test = test;
});
```

Then adding components individually until it breaks or works as expected. A great approach when dealing with multiple new technologies and concepts.